# Cannot load Pinia in Nuxt3

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, pinia

I am trying to set up Nuxt3 to work with Pinia.

**Steps Taken:**

- Started with an active nuxt3 project
- ran `npm install @pinia/nuxt`
- this failed, with a dependency error, so re-ran with `npm install @pinia/nuxt --legacy-peer-deps`, which worked fine
- added pinia to my nuxt.config.ts, which now looks like:

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    meta: {
        link: [
            {
                rel: "stylesheet",
                href:"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            }
        ],
      script: [
        { src: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', integrity: 'sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2', crossorigin: 'anonymous' }
      ]
    },
    ssr: false,
    buildModules: ['@pinia/nuxt'],
    base: '/',
})
```

- restarted the server
- got the following error:

`GET http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/@id/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

I've been googling around, and can't figure out what's broken here... I tried taking out the 'base' argument in nuxt.config.ts, and that didn't help either. If I take out the pinia declaration everything works fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Resolved by running:
`npm install pinia @pinia/nuxt @nuxtjs/composition-api --legacy-peer-deps`

I guess I was missing the actual pinia library

Comment: I used "npm install pinia @pinia/nuxt  --legacy-peer-deps "and installed without error.  what is purpose of using @nuxtjs/composition-api  package?

Comment: @nuxtjs/composition-api is for Nuxt2 only and enables the use of the composition api. Seems to be useless here.

Comment: I tried the official approach by adding the overrides property to my package.json but was still getting errors. Resolved it by installing like so: `npm install pinia @pinia/nuxt --legacy-peer-deps`.

Answer (score 4):

In the Nuxt [docs](https://pinia.vuejs.org/ssr/nuxt.html) they suggest adding this to your package.json before running npm install:

```
"overrides": {
  "vue": "latest"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i had a same problem and solve it install with
yarn add @pinia/nuxt
instead npm

Answer (score 0):

[image: NuxtJS DOC]

In the NuxtJS DOC ther's a guide that will help you on this.

Comment: adding this results in `Override for vue@^3.3.13 conflicts with direct dependency`